# How do I view the older versions of a config spec file?

Tags: version, clearcase, config-spec

## Background

You can view the version history of a file graphically with the command:

`ct lsvtree -gra <filename>`

Or textually with:

`ct lshist <filename>`

In addition, the **current** configspec file can be viewed with:

`ct edcs`

## Problem

I am trying to view previous versions of my view's configspec. However, using either command above, replacing `<filename>` with `edcs` does not work. The page on [config_spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm) doesn't talk about anything related to the history of configspec.

## Question

How can I view the previous version of a view's configspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not natively supported, you need to set it up somehow:

- take a dynamic view with a repo dedicated to config spec
- write your config spec for a new view and store that as a file within said dedicated view
- use the config spec with [`cleartool setcs -tag viewTag /path/to/config/spec/file`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setcs.htm)

That way, ant time you want to make changes to your current config spec, write those changes first in that file, and re-setcs to your view.

Then and only then would you get historization of your config spec.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't unless you keep configspec files under source control or use UCM.

In UCM, if you know the baselines you moved from, you can create new stream based on the prior baselines and examine the files.

This begs a followon question: What are you looking for that you hope to find in the prior configspec?